# "Flip" events in non-Safari webkit mobile browsers?

Tags: android, jquery, iphone, cross-browser, webkit

A recent [Ajaxian post title "Swipe away, then quickly flip with simple jQuery plugins"](http://ajaxian.com/archives/swipe-flip-iphone) tells us about flip events on the iPhone Safari browser and I wanted to use them on another webkit browser, the Android Browser.

```
$('.swipe').swipe({

     swipeLeft: function() { $('#someDiv').fadeIn() },

     swipeRight: function() { $('#someDiv').fadeOut() },

})
```

The event is triggered, but it still scrolls the page left and right. Anyone know a work around for this? I'd love to see the plugin get whatever fix is possible, so it works in more places, of course.